# How to make Apache pass control to Laravel for specific URLs

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel route for `/ad-reports/` and `/ad-reports/promos` that worked fine until I put directories matching those names inside `public`.  Why did I do that?  I need them for caching, so that a request for (e.g.) `/ad-reports/promos/12345.pdf` gets handled by Laravel if there is no PDF named `12345.pdf` saved inside `public/ad-reports/promos`, but by Apache if the PDF has already been created and saved there.

I don't want to mess with my URL structure (the whole point of having routing is so we're not forced to let the file system dictate our URLs) and of course I can't afford to give up the caching.

How can I force Apache to ignore requests for `/ad-reports/` and `/ad-reports/promos`, but handle everything that it *should* handle?

Or alternately (and better, actually) how can I make Apache ignore requests for folders, and only respond to requests for specific files, letting Laravel handle anything that does not match a file inside `public`?

Comment: May you show your .htaccess in public?

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line from your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It tells apache to handle the directory if the directory exists, but you only need it to handle if the file exists, which is done by the `-f` line.